# unable to create ActiveX object using javascript

Tags: javascript, command-prompt, windows-console

i want to rum command using Windows Command Prompt but it require ActiveX object... Mozilla FireFox4 and Google Chrome are giving error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

ActiveXObject is only supported in IE. This is not a standard object and specific to IE and hence Windows. Other browsers runs on multiple platforms and it doesn't make sense for them to implement this non standard object.

Comment: how can i open notepad using javascript? without ActiveXObject

Comment: If you are talking about "javascript in browser", then you cann't do that and there is no reason you should be doing that. Think about this, if you can open notepad from JS code then any web site can run "format your hard drive" program as soon as you open the web site.

Answer (score 1):

Only Internet Explorer allows for running ActiveX objects.